# Launching multiple Docker containers with supervisor

Tags: docker, supervisord

I've got a number of Docker containers which I would like to start using `supervisor`. The problem I have is that supervisor requires commands to be blocking to keep track of them.

The command `docker run my/container:tag` is unfortunately non-blocking, i.e. it returns immediately spawning a process.

The docker container gets launched (actually 2 and sometimes 4 instances which may be related), but supervisor indicates an error "FATAL      Exited too quickly (process log may have details)".

Can supervisor be used to run Docker containers?

**Update**

I had the `-d` option also on from some earlier trials which cause `-i` to not work as expected (aren't they the opposite and shouldn't they prompt some sort of error?). When I run with `-i` in my `supervisor.conf`, I get this error `time="2015-06-27T14:14:29+10:00" level=fatal msg="cannot enable tty mode on non tty input"`.

I've also tried to run without `-i` and it successfully starts the docker container. Unfortunately a `sudo supervisorctl stop app` does not actually stop the docker container. Is supervisor unable to control docker or do I really need to run with the `-i` option and fix this tty error somehow?

**Update 2**

The tty error came from also having the `-t` option in my `docker run` command. I removed it. However, `supervisorctl` is still not able to stop the docker run. While it doesn't give an error when running and `supervisorctl status app` says it has stopped with `docker ps` I see that the container is actually still running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you run your container with the [`-i` option](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#foreground), it will block

`docker run -i my/container:tag`

Comment: When I tried this from the command line, it returned immediately and printed a container id. I will try again.

Comment: Resolved it by upgrading to `Docker version 1.7.0-dev, build 9234460`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run container in interactive mode. This would be the blocking call and if you are blocking until the new process exits then following is the correct command:

```
docker run -i -t my/container:tag
```

Comment: Tried it and it works sort of. Running into a new issue now. Please see my update.

Comment: Yes .. -i and -t lets u run the container in interactive mode with tty.


I think the issue you are having is because the process which demonizes your container exits immediately thats why supervisor thinks the process exited already.

Comment: The process inside the docker container is also triggered with `supervisor`, but with the `-no--daemon` option enabled. I think I just resolved the issue by upgrading to the latest Docker version (from 1.5.0). I'm running with `-i` and without `-t` and now and it works fine. Thanks for your help.